# credit card validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, credit-card

The code is not validating the values correctly, when i put in a simple digit it is already triggering the code.

```
$(".validate-card-num").live('keypress', function() {
    var ccNum = $(this).val();
    //var visa = /^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$/;
    //var master = /^5[1-5]([0-9]{14})$/;

    if(ccNum.test(/^4[0-9]{12}([0-9]{3})?$/)){
        $("#img-visa").css("opacity","1");
        $("#img-master").css("opacity","0.3");
    }else if(ccNum.test(/^5[1-5]([0-9]{14})$/)){
        $("#img-master").css("opacity","1");
        $("#img-visa").css("opacity","0.3");
    }else
        $("#img-master, #img-visa").css("opacity","0.3")

});
```

for example i put in "5" the value triggers the regex but when i put in another value it disables the regex all together.

Comment: What is the symptom of it failing? Is it crashing, or just not doing what you want/think it should.

Comment: Please don't tag your question with [tag:jquery-validate] if you're not using the jQuery Validation plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the `.test()` function correctly.
This function is only available in RegExObject, and you are using it on a string.
Your code should be like this:

```
var ccNum = "Test CC";
var visa = new  RegExp("Paste Your Visa Pattern Here");
//Then do the check
if(visa.test(ccNum)){
   console.log('visa card');
}else{
   console.log('not visa card');
}
```